# How to require the user's password when you want to update the user's information in the Firebase JSON tree?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, passwords, firebase

I've got a form which is used to update a user's information, both in the Firebase JSON tree and the seperate database which holds the email + password combination for the users. Whenever you want to update either the email or password, you need to provide an email + password combination for it to work.

However, when you only want to update the JSON tree you can do it without a password. My form requires you to enter your current password before anything can happen, but if you type in the wrong password it will still update the display name of the user.

So my question is, is there a way that I can require the **correct** password before actually updating anything in the database?

The code in my controller:

```
//If the user has entered a new display name
if (sharedInfo.getUser().displayName !== $scope.user.displayName) {

    var isNameChanged = userLogic.changeDisplayName($scope.user);
        isNameChanged.then(function(isSuccessful) {

            if (isSuccessful === true) {
                $scope.isSuccessful = true;
            }
            else {
                $scope.error = 'Update failed';
            }
        });
}
```

Function in my service:

```
changeDisplayName: function(user) {

    //Get the user ID
    var userData = sharedInfo.getAuthState();

    return fbRef.getSyncedReference('users/' + userData.uid).$update({displayName: user.displayName}).then(function() {
        return true;
    }, function(error) {
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: The correct methodology here is to [authenticate the user](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html), and utilize [security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/) to control read/write access (e.g. `".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"`).

Comment: @Kato That's what I thought, so I can't implement the "current password" input with this in any way whatsoever?